# Identifying Parts Used For The Escape Hatch of Sariel's Tiger XL Model

Tags: technic, part-identification, building, piece-usage

I am working on a similar model of [Sariel's Tiger XL](http://sariel.pl/2014/09/tiger-xl/) in prep for my own designs of a few other German WW2 tanks, and need some help identifying a part or two.

Does anyone know what are the two parts on the left image that stand in for the escape hatch? One looks like a spanner, and the other one behind it is circular.

[image: build photo]

Comment: Great question! Welcome to Bricks.SE!

Comment: I think Sariel needs his own tag for Bricks:SE!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***First three from what we can see...***

[image]

1. [Part: 4735 Bar 1 x 3 with Clip and Stud Receptacle (Robot Arm)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4735&rm)&category=%5BBar%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).

[image]

2. [Part 2958 Technic, Disk 3 x 3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=2848#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).

[image]

3. [Part: 75c03 Hose, Rigid 3mm D. 3L / 2.4cm](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=39445#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).

***Last two hidden from view...***

[image]
4 & 5. [Part: 4085d Plate, Modified 1 x 1 with Clip Vertical - Type 4
    (thick open O clip)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4085d&name=Plate,%20Modified%201%20x%201%20with%20Clip%20Vertical%20-%20Type%204%20(thick%20open%20O%20clip)&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=S&C=85&O=%7B%22color%22:%2285%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D).

I can't see, but I can imagine two crossed vertical 1x1 clip plates, pierced by the flex tubing to hold up the robot arm.

***Sing! Now, build it out.  Now, build it out.  Now, build it out...***
[image]

Comment: Great answer! That's a good call about likely having the 85861 element behind to secure it in place. It could just be held in place by the antistud on the arm, but I'm sure that Sariel designs with a lot more robustness than the MOCs that I cobble together. :)

Comment: True, or possibly a combination of both.  Darn-it!  Now I have to make another animation!:(

Answer (score 4):

This is actually made of three parts as far as I can tell.

- **[Technic Disk 3 x 3](https://rebrickable.com/parts/2723/technic-disk-3-x-3/)** (2723)

[image: Technic Disk 3 x 3]

- **[Bar 1 x 3 [Clip / Anti-Stud]](https://rebrickable.com/parts/4735/bar-1-x-3-clip-anti-stud/)** (4735)

[image: Bar 1 x 3]

- A cut piece of **[Hose, Rigid 3mm](https://rebrickable.com/search/?search_type=parts&q=75&part_cat=30&exists_in_color=&min_year=1990&max_year=2018&min_part_cost=0&max_part_cost=20#parts)** aka Flex System tubing

[image: Hose, Rigid 3mm]